# How to keep submit button from shrinking, making it non-responsive?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple page with two buttons in a much larger site.  One button shrinks when the page is resized -- for example, when I open the bookmarks flyout in Firefox, or when I display the page at larger and smaller sizes using ctrl-plus and ctrl-minus or the mouse wheel.

The left edge of the non-responsive button stays anchored to the same point, but the right edge shrinks (moves toward the left), unlike other page elements, so its size in relation to the other elements changes, making it non-responsive.

This button does not shrink:

```
<div class="ttg_text_grid2">
   <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">Select file</label>
     <input id="file-upload" type="file"/>
    </label>
</div>
```

This button shrinks:

```
<div class="ttg_text_grid3">
<button class="custom-file-upload" id="submit_btn" type="submit" value="Submit" onsubmit="submit_btn.disabled = true; return true;">Take action</button></div>
```

There is also text at the top of the page that does not shrink.

Here is the relevant css:

```
.ttg_text_grid2 {
  grid-column: 9 / 15;
  grid-row: 6 / 19;
  padding-left: 22.5%;
}

.ttg_text_grid3 {
  grid-column: 9 / 15;
  grid-row: 6 / 19;
  padding-left: 11%;
}

.custom-file-upload {
  border: 1px solid rgb(117,163,126);
  background-color: black;
  width: 65%;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Sans-serif;
  font-size: 13pt;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(255,255,255);
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=file] {
  display: none;
}
```

Based on the html and css above, why does the first button size not change size and the second button shrinks and expands?

This is important for responsive design.  The entire site is css grid, and everything else on the site is responsive except this.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: If you changed the markup on the second one to be an input instead of a button, what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main point is that its width is in %; So obviously it should shrink and expand.
Try to remove width property from css.

Use padding instead to keep the button size always the same, or just use static size in px.

Answer (score 2):

Your class of `.custom-file-upload` has a percentage based width value.  By changing it to `200px` for example, will ensure that it does not change size depending on the screensize.

```
.custom-file-upload {
    border: 1px solid rgb(117,163,126);
    background-color: black;
    width: 65%; <!-- change this to to a px value -->
    padding: 8px 20px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Sans-serif;
    font-size: 13pt;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Your answer and Orkhan Ismayilov are the same.  I think you both have it right, makes perfect sense.  I'll try that now and let you know what happens.

Comment: Yes, you guys are both right.  Thanks much.  I chose Orkhan as best answer because he said it first.  I'd choose both answers as best if I could.